# kafka-connect-fs to connect SFTP using Key File or Passwordless Entry

Tags: apache-kafka, sftp, apache-kafka-connect, jsch

I'm trying to integrate Kafka Connect FS & Source SFTP with Username & Passwordless Entry(Private key). But I'm getting AUTH Failure with below settings.

Its completely working fine with `username:password@hostname:port` format for a Test SFTP Location, but actual source doesnt allow password based authentication.

Even i tried, "fs.sftp.keyfile". but no luck.

Here is my Property file:

```
name=SourceConnector
connector.class=com.github.mmolimar.kafka.connect.fs.FsSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
policy.fs.fs.sftp.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem
fs.uris=sftp://username:@hostname:22/home/user/output/
fs.sftp.keyfile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
topic=sampletopic
policy.class=com.github.mmolimar.kafka.connect.fs.policy.CronPolicy
policy.recursive=true
file_reader.delimited.settings.data_type_mapping_error=false
file_reader.delimited.settings.allow_nulls=true
policy.regexp=^SOURCE_1.*.gz$
policy.batch_size=0
policy.cleanup=none
file_reader.class=com.github.mmolimar.kafka.connect.fs.file.reader.CsvFileReader
file_reader.batch_size=3000
policy.cron.expression=0/30 * * ? * * *
file_reader.delimited.compression.type=gzip
```

Please help me to connect with private key. Thanks

```
ERROR FsSourceTask Cannot retrieve files to process from the FS: [[]]. There was an error executing the policy but the task tolerates this and continues: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

Comment: Validated Private key is of format - ***BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY****, because Openssh format was not supported by JSCH

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve this error with below config:

`policy.fs.fs.sftp.keyfile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`